# How do I tell pylint about a descriptor providing access to iterables, subscriptables?

Tags: python, python-decorators, pylint, python-descriptors

I have a decorator that I can use to mark a read-only class property:

```
class class_ro_property(property):
    def __init__(self, getter:Callable):
        self._getter = getter

    def __get__(self, _, cls):
        return self._getter(cls)

class MyClass:
    @class_ro_property
    def my_property(cls):
        return [1, 2, 3]
```

The problem is that pylint doesn't understand this at all.  If I try to write:

```
for num in MyClass.my_property:
    print(num)
```

it will tell me:

```
E1133:0035:Non-iterable value MyClass.my_property is used in an iterating context
```

The same problem happens if I try to subscript it, ie `MyClass.my_property[0]`.

Is there some way to tell pylint about the use of a descriptor here?  If not, is there some way to tell pylint **at the property definition** (and not only where it's used) not to complain about its use in an iterating context?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `property`?

Comment: @Jasmijn I mean, they are, it's just that it won't work on class variables so the derived from `property` to get that behavior

Comment: Ah I see. I think I know how to answer your question now.

Comment: By the way, is `self_getter` a transcription error or is it present in your code too? (Should be `self._getter`)

Comment: @Jasmijn yes, it's a transcription error.  Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight answer is: that is a short-comming of the linter. A feature request should be open against "pylint" pointing to the fact it does not recognize descriptors.

That said, just strap a comment to skip linting where you are getting this problem as a workaround. Adding a comment like # pylint: disable=E1133 on the offending line should do the job.

When coding Python, one has to keep in mind that auxiliary tooling like linters and static type checkers do not have how to know everything that happens at runtime. Not recognizing a descriptor, like here, is a shortcoming of pylint, and they could implement the feature (though I doubt they will) - but there are other cases where that is not feasible at all.

(Judging by the other answer, pylint opts for special casing the `property` call, but ignores that `property` itself is just one use-case of descriptors)

By the way, I can't find this specific error in the pylint error codes at http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes - maybe it is provided by an specific extension? You might just want to throw away such an extension if it is doing more harm than good.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer.  I've raised a ticket on pylint after discussing it on their discord.  We'll see if they do anything with it.

Comment: If you want a similar example, the static typing team on Python itself had to come up with  the `typing.dataclass_transform` decorator to overcome the static type checking inability to follow dynamic code such as the one used by dataclasses. Previously, they had just specialcased `dataclasses.dataclass`  just as pylint special cased `property`.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be to write a metaclass that defines the property:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    @property
    def my_property(cls):
        return [1, 2, 3]

class MyClass(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    my_property = MyClassMeta.my_property

for num in MyClass.my_property:
    print(num)
```

Pylint is fine with that use of `MyClass.my_property`. Note that if you don't need `MyClass().my_property` to get it on instances, you can omit the line `my_property = MyClassMeta.my_property`.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm not going to down-vote this but I'm not keen.  For one thing, it's not an answer to the question.  For another thing, someone did exactly that in this code and then left the company.  The rest of us spent several months looking at the code and wondering what the hell was going on with it before I decided to refactor it using the `class_ro_property` decorator.  To your average Python programmer, metaclasses are very black magic indeed and this seems like a major maintainability hit (and a hit we've already paid once).

Comment: You could add `# pylint: disable=not-an-iterable` at the end of any line where you iterate over `MyClass.my_property`. Otherwise I don't think there is a solution where you both avoid adding a metaclass and make pylint happy.

Comment: Okay.  I've raised a ticket (#7820) on Pylint.